# Template overload for container of values vs container of smart ptr

Tags: c++, c++14

New to templates so I think a code snippet will best illustrate my problem.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <type_traits>


template <typename TContainer, typename T>
bool contains(const TContainer& container, const T& t){
    auto begin = container.begin();
    auto end   = container.end();
    auto predicate = [&t](const auto& cT){
        return cT == t;
    };
    auto iter = std::find_if(begin, end, predicate);

    return iter != end;
}

struct Foo{
    int _value;
    Foo(int value) : _value{value} {}

    bool operator==(const Foo& other) const{
        return _value == other._value;
    }
};


int main(){
    using SmartFoo      = std::shared_ptr<Foo>;
    auto valueContainer = std::vector<Foo>{{1},{2},{3}};
    auto ptrContainer   = std::vector<SmartFoo>{{std::make_unique<Foo>(1)},
                                                {std::make_unique<Foo>(2)},
                                                {std::make_unique<Foo>(3)}};

    auto needle         = Foo(2);
    auto smartNeedle    = std::make_shared<Foo>(3);

    auto found          = contains(valueContainer, needle);
    auto smartFound     = contains(ptrContainer, smartNeedle);

    std::cout<<std::boolalpha;
    std::cout<<"Found by value?: " <<  found << "\n";
    std::cout<<"Found by smartptr?: " << smartFound << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Essentially I have some containers that hold smart pointers, and some containers that hold value objects but in both cases I am only interested in the value objects itself. 
The **output** of the above is

```
Found by value?: true
Found by smartptr?: false
```

Which is obviously because `operator==` for `shared_ptr` checks adresses and not content.

I am struggling with implementing a predicate that will derference T if T is a smart ptr so the comparison happens on the value and not the adress. Ideally I would like to pass either type of container to the same `contains`. Is either option possible? And if so, how?

Comment: I changed the C++11 tag to C++14 because C++11 doesn't support generic lambdas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use overload:

```
template <typename T>
bool cmp_value(const T& lhs, const T& rhs)
{
    return lhs == rhs;
}

template <typename T>
bool cmp_value(const std::shared_ptr<T>& lhs, const std::shared_ptr<T>& rhs)
{
    return *lhs == *rhs;
}
```

and then

```
template <typename TContainer, typename T>
bool contains(const TContainer& container, const T& t){
    auto begin = container.begin();
    auto end   = container.end();
    auto predicate = [&t](const auto& cT){
        return cmp_value(cT, t);
    };
    auto iter = std::find_if(begin, end, predicate);

    return iter != end;
}
```

Comment: Didn't think of this, so simple yet perfect! Thank you

Comment: I wish the standard library would let me check if a type is a smart ptr though, like std::is_pointer

Comment: You can create the traits simply with: `template <typename T> struct is_shared_ptr : std::false_type {};
template <typename T> struct is_shared_ptr<std::shared_ptr<T>> : std::true_type {};
`

Answer (score 2):

You can do like the standard library does and provide an overload that takes a comparator.  Then if you want to use the default `operator ==` you call the function without specifying a comparator and if you need a special(more involved) comparison you pass that to the function.

```
template <typename TContainer, typename T>
bool contains(const TContainer& container, const T& t){
    auto begin = container.begin();
    auto end   = container.end();
    auto predicate = [&t](const auto& cT){
        return cT == t;
    };
    auto iter = std::find_if(begin, end, predicate);

    return iter != end;
}

template <typename TContainer, typename T, typename Compare>
bool contains(const TContainer& container, const T& t, Compare comp){
    auto begin = container.begin();
    auto end   = container.end();
    auto predicate = [&t, &comp](const auto& cT){
        return comp(cT, t);
    };
    auto iter = std::find_if(begin, end, predicate);

    return iter != end;
}
```